# grep access_token in bash script from the URL

Tags: bash, shell

Wants to get the access_token from the url below in bash script.

```
http://localhost:4200/loginoauth2#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4ZTAxNTM1MWfddfRmMzEyMzczMTk4NTUxNjYyODRiMWI1MCIsImV4cCI6MTU5NTI1NzYwMiwic3ViIjoiZm9nsddssbWFuIn0.Sr3FT4EdssdsbddnBUR4VgKfPdAhaqvdGKKCJKV8gWLa3xhJwcfg_I3pjnHuYdsfsdfsdfsdfsd0zVD_MYNqqmLMqNRbdeeDTXgtveWmlErQ&expires_in=3600&scope=all&state=3d417058-50a5-49&token_type=Bearer
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
echo 'http://localhost:4200/loginoauth2#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4ZTAxNTM1MWfddfRmMzEyMzczMTk4NTUxNjYyODRiMWI1MCIsImV4cCI6MTU5NTI1NzYwMiwic3ViIjoiZm9nsddssbWFuIn0.Sr3FT4EdssdsbddnBUR4VgKfPdAhaqvdGKKCJKV8gWLa3xhJwcfg_I3pjnHuYdsfsdfsdfsdfsd0zVD_MYNqqmLMqNRbdeeDTXgtveWmlErQ' |  
sed 's/.*access_token=\([^&]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
URL="http://localhost:4200/loginoauth2#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4ZTAxNTM1MWRmMzEyMzczMTk4NTUxNjYyODRiMWI1MCIsImV4cCI6MTU5NTI1NzYwMiwic3ViIjoiZm9nbWFuIn0.Sr3FT4EnBUR4VgKfPdAhaqvdGKKCJKV8gWLa3xhJwcfg_I3pjnHuY0zVD_MYNqqmLMqNRbdeeDTXgtveWmlErQ&expires_in=3600&scope=all&state=3d417058-50a5-49&token_type=Bearer"

token=$(echo $URL | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d '&' -f 1)

echo $token
```

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: you wrap quotes for strings, the double quotes allow variable replacement while single quotes do not

Comment: Read the link. You are presuming that the resulting token contains no shell metacharacters, but this is not a safe assumption for inputs you do not control.

Comment: Oh! ok, thanks for clarification :)